# Getting 403 Forbidden error while deploying Django project

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy django project on my local server which accessible through internet and getting this error:
You don't have permission to access /projectname/projectname.fcgi on this server.

I am using this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#s-running-django-on-a-shared-hosting-provider-with-apache

Any help on this? I am new to django and this is my first project.

Comment: What's your file permissions and owner of that file and folder?

Comment: Owner is whisperqaftpuser and permission is drwxrwxrwx+.

Comment: Try doing `chown www-data -R` on your django app folder. Assuming you're using Apache

Comment: I have centos and i have already given 777 recursive permission to my app folder.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `chown youruser:www-data -R`

Comment: _"I have centos and i have already given 777 recursive permission to my app folder."_ - this is probably why its not working. 777 is almost never the answer. Can you post the Apache error log and also `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: 1) (104) Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server     2) Premature end of script headers: filename.fcgi

Comment: Another issue is that i have installed python2.6 before and now i have python2.7 but script always refer to old python.